# How to retrieve the first non blank cell and value of any dynamic rows in vba

Tags: vba, excel, row

```
Set rngFound = Rows(5).Find("*", Cells(Columns.Count, 5), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlNext)
```

The above code gives the type mismatch error 13.

Kindly advise what I am doing wrong, or suggest any other method of doing the same.

Comment: can you share the rest of your relevant code ? how is `rngFound` defined, which worksheet are you trying to use `Find` , etc.

Comment: rngfound is defined as varriant or range and If I am replacing Rows with columns then same line of code works  but I am not able to find the non blank value of a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Dim rngFound  As Range
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim nonBlankCell As Variant

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- modify to your sheet's name
    ' -- get last column in a specific row by using the Find function --
    Set rngFound = .Rows(5).Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then ' Find was successful
        LastCol = rngFound.Column ' get last Column with data
        nonBlankCell = rngFound.Value
    End If

End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this code is still showing type mismatch error 13, problem is in the line Set rngFound = .Rows(5).Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

Comment: Hey, It works Thanks could u please tell me what is the issue in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Cells(Columns.Count, 5)` with `Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)` to get

```
Set rngFound = Rows(5).Find("*", Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlNext)
```

Try this

```
Sub Find_Cell()
    Dim rngFound  As Range
    Set rngFound = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(5).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues)

    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "All cells are blank."
    Else
        MsgBox "First Cell Address: " & rngFound.Address
        MsgBox "First Cell Value: " & rngFound.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

If you also want to find non blank cell having a formula equating to blank then instead of `LookIn:=xlValues` use `LookIn:=xlFormulas`